# How to get a random element from an object in AS3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object, random, element

You can get a random element from an array like below

```
var list:Array=[1,2,3,4,5];
var randomElement:int = list[ int(Math.random()*list.length) ] ;
```

But how to get a random element from an object?

```
var list:Object={a:0,b:1,c:1};
var randomElement:int = //from the list..how??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create temporary array of keys for example:

```
    var list:Object={a:0,b:1,c:2};
    var keys:Array = [];
    for(var key:String in list)
        keys[keys.length] = key;

    var randomElement:int = list[keys[ int(Math.random()*keys.length) ]];
```

It's quite expensive to create new array each time you need a random property of an object, but I don't see other options to get it.

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative ( for this special case ):

```
 var list:Object={ a:0,b:1,c:2 };
 var max_i:Number = "c".charCodeAt( 0 );
 var min_i:Number = "a".charCodeAt( 0 );
 var range:Number = max_i - min_i ;
 var rand_i:Number = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( range + 1 ) );

 var prop:String = String.fromCharCode( min_i + rand_i );
 var randomElement:int = list[ prop ];

 trace( prop , randomElement );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

```
var list:Object = {a:0,b:1,c:1};
var keyCount:int = 3; //number of keys
var randomElement:String;

var randProb:Number = 1.0 / keyCount;

for (randomElement in list)
{
    if (Math.random() < randProb)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        randProb += 1.0 / keyCount;
    }
}

trace(list[randomElement]);
```